# PyGTK: Trouble with size of ScrolledWindow

Tags: python, pygtk, gtktreeview, gtkscrolledwindow

I am using PyGTK and the `gtk.Assistant`. On one page I have placed a treeview (one column, just strings) in a `gtk.ScrolledWindow` (I wanted the vertical scrollbar, since the list contains about 35 items). Everything is working fine; the only thing that bugs me is that I have not been able to figure out from the documentation how to set the size of the scrolled window. Currently only three items are displayed at a time; I would like to set this number to 10 or so.

Below is the code. As you can see I have tried using a `gtk.Adjustment` to influence the scrolled window's size, but as - once more - I have been incompetent at retrieving the required info from the documentation, I don't actually know what values should be put into there.

```
    self.page7 = gtk.VBox()

    # The gtk.Adjustment:
    page_size    = gtk.Adjustment(lower=10, page_size=100) # just used some arbitrary numbers here >_<
    scrolled_win = gtk.ScrolledWindow(page_size)
    scrolled_win.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC) # only display scroll bars when required

    self.character_traits_treeview  = gtk.TreeView()
    self.character_traits_treestore = gtk.TreeStore(str)
    self.character_traits_treeview.set_model(self.character_traits_treestore)

    tc = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Character traits")
    self.character_traits_treeview.append_column(tc)
    cr = gtk.CellRendererText()
    tc.pack_start(cr, True)
    tc.add_attribute(cr, "text", 0)

    self.character_trait_selection = self.character_traits_treeview.get_selection()
    self.character_trait_selection.connect('changed', self.check_number_of_character_trait_selections)
    self.character_trait_selection.set_mode(gtk.SELECTION_MULTIPLE)

    self.make_character_traits_treestore()

    # adding the treeview to the scrolled window:
    scrolled_win.add(self.character_traits_treeview)
    self.page7.pack_start(scrolled_win, False, False, 0)

    self.assistant.append_page(self.page7)
    self.assistant.set_page_title(self.page7, "Step 7: Select 2-3 character traits")
    self.assistant.set_page_type(self.page7, gtk.ASSISTANT_PAGE_CONTENT)
    self.assistant.set_page_complete(self.page7, False)

def check_number_of_character_trait_selections(self, blah):
    # ...

def make_character_traits_treestore(self):
    # ...
```

I know I should RTFM, but as I can't make head or tail of it, and as further searching, too, has been to no avail, I'm just hoping that someone on here can give me a hint.

Thanks a lot in advance!

PS: Here are the links to:

- the [gtk.ScrolledWindow documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkscrolledwindow.html)
- the [gtk.Adjustment documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkadjustment.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been very, very stupid, it was merely a packing issue >_<

This line

```
self.page7.pack_start(scrolled_win, False, False, 0)
```

should read

```
self.page7.pack_start(scrolled_win, True, True, 0)
```

instead!

Now everything's looking the way I want it to look.